# Django -- Process Multiple Form Fields

Tags: python, django, forms

I am very new to Python / Django and would appreciate any and all help I can get here!

I am trying to take in multiple form fields and haven't been able to find a great clean way to do so. My code is trying to take in a foreign Key radio selection (the team), and a number (the bet size), for each instance.

I ended up creating the code to iterate over the request.POST.items to determine which game each team belongs to, which is working fine, however I am having trouble taking in the input for the Bet size as the "value" field is already being assigned to each game.

I have debated using a model form instead of the methodology I have chosen, but cannot find a great way to take in the foreign key data.

How would you suggest altering the code to take in the bet size field? Is there an alternative way to process using Model Forms that you would suggest?

Please find my code below!

Thanks in advance

Views.py:

```
def pick_game(request):
# Check what kind of request this is? GET/POST?
if request.method == 'GET':
    game_list = Game.objects.order_by('-picks')
    # form = PickGameForm()
    page_variables = {
        "game_list": game_list, 'form':form
    }
    return render(request, 'social/pickGame.html', page_variables)
else:

    for key, value in request.POST.items():
        print(key, value)
        if "choice" in key:
            game_id = int(key.split("_")[1])
            team_id = int(value)
            game = Game.objects.get(pk=game_id)
            team = Team.objects.get(pk=team_id)
            PlayerPick.objects.create(
                player_profile=request.user.playerprofile,
                game=game,
                team=team,
                bet_size=bet_size
            )

        else:
            bet_size = request.POST.get('Bet')
```

pickGame.html:

```
<h1>Games</h1>

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for game in game_list %}

        <h2>Game {{ game.number }}</h2>

        <p><input type="radio" name="{{ game.pk }}" value="{{ game.team1.pk }}"> {{ game.team1.name }}</p>
        <p><input type="radio" name="{{ game.pk }}" value="{{ game.team2.pk }}"> {{ game.team2.name }}</p>
        <p><input type="number" name="Bet"> How much Money? </p>

    {% endfor %}
    <hr>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

PlayerPick model:

```
class PlayerPick(models.Model):
player_profile = models.ForeignKey('PlayerProfile')
team = models.ForeignKey('Team')
game = models.ForeignKey('Game')
bet_size = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True)
correct = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
pick_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: what is your question

Comment: Apologies, just altered the question to be more specific: How would you suggest altering the code to take in the bet size field? Is there an alternative way to process using Model Forms that you would suggest?

Comment: Post code for `PlayerPick` model

Comment: Just added. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your manual approach is quite OK, and all you have to do is find a way to uniquely identify the Bet field for each game. You could to this in your html:

```
<input type="number" name="{{game.pk}}-Bet">
```

And then get the value in your view just before creating your PlayerPick object:

```
bet_size = request.POST.get('%s-Bet' % game.pk)
```

If you want to use Django Forms, you can also imitate this behaviour by using the `prefix` parameter when creating your form. You have to define this both for the unbound and bound forms, so that the prefixed field names can be recognized:

```
# When creating the forms and passing them to the template
PlayerPickForm(prefix=str(game.pk)+'-')

# When verifying posted data
PlayerPickForm(request.POST, prefix=str(game.pk)+'-')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This makes a lot of sense. When you define bet_size in the post.get, do you mean game_id after the % instead of game.pk? Game.pk would not be defined, but game_id is defined above by splitting the choose key. Do you think there is a better way to take the game as an input?

Comment: Yes, they should ultimately be the same if you do `game = Game.objects.get(pk=game_id)` because `game.pk` is defined by `game_id` in your query. Just use whichever value is available to you. Anyways, you get the idea: repeat the fields in a single form, but find a way to match each Bet field name to its Game.